# One trig "survives" a binomial summation: why?

Tags: reference-request, real-analysis, cv.complex-variables, fourier-analysis, combinatorial-identities

I've seen many trigonometric identities but here is one that I encountered for which I did not find a reference.

In case you wonder where this came from, I was investigating certain $q$-series [in this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1203.6736.pdf) on Eulerian polynomials.

> **Question.** Is this true? Can you provide a reference or a proof?
>   $$\sum_{k=-n}^n\frac{2k+1}{n+k+1}\binom{2n}{n-k}\sec((2k+1)\theta)=\sec((2n+1)\theta).$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The sum from k=-n to k=n-1 equals zero by pairing off the end terms and by using the sign difference together with the evenness of the function sec.

Comment: Ahh, too easy. Thanks all the same.